# Value of TextBox searched and jump to a cell by clicking a button in the UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VB code in which I made a button in Excel that when clicked, goes to the next sheet and searches for the value based on employee number. I used `VLookup` in this code. My problem is solved.

The same thing I am doing with UserForm in Excel. Now I have a `textbox1` for employee number and `textbox2` for employee name, the same is in `sheet2` with `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

Now when I enter the employee number in `textbox1`, the name is appearing in `textbox2` and also a button to change the value of `textbox2`.

I want to change the value of `textbox2` and when the button is clicked, go to that particular employees name field.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you already have code that doesn't work or are you asking to write something based on your requirements?

Comment: You should try somethings and post that code if found error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below piece of code

```
Dim i As Long
Dim rno As Integer
i = 0

Do While Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text Then

            rno = Sheets(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).Row
            GoTo Condition
        Else
        rno = 0

        End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Condition:
If rno <> 0 Then
    Sheets(2).Cells(rno, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
Else
    MsgBox ("No Such number is found")
End If
```